# estado' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

Segue o código:

```
var resultado = db.Tabela
        .Where(l => l.Nome == "João")
        .Select(l => new { l.numero, l.cidade, l.estado, l.pais });
```

Sei que no banco de dados tem valor de "SP" do campo estado e eu quero alterar o valor "SP" para "São Paulo".

Aqui está o `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in resultado.Where(u => u.estado == "SP"))
{
    item.estado= "São Paulo";
}
```

Recebo o seguinte de **erro**:

> estado' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Alguma solução?

**UPDATE:**

Já tentei dessa forma:

```
var resultado = db.Tabela
                   .Where(l => l.Nome == "João")
                   .Select(l => new { l.numero, l.cidade, l.estado, l.pais }).ToList();
```

For:

```
for (int i = 0; i <resultado.Count; i++)
{
    if (resultado[i].estado== "SP")
    {
        resultado[i].estado= "São Paulo";
    }                    
}
```

e ainda continua o mesmo **erro**.

Comment: É `Entity Framework`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sim

Comment: ve se ficou claro...

Comment: Ficou muito bom @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Porque não funciona?

Está retornando um objeto [desconhecido](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb397696.aspx) ([anonimo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb397696.aspx)) e os seus elementos são tratados como `readOnly` (*somente leitura*), então para funcionar traga o objeto na sua totalidade sem `Select`, faça assim:

```c#
var resultado = db.Tabela
                  .Where(l => l.Nome == "João" && l.estado == "SP")
                  .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < resultado.Count(); i++)
{
    resultado[i].estado = "São Paulo";
}

db.SaveChanges(); // salvar as alterações.
```

Não estou adentrando se isso é a melhor forma, ou o seu desempenho é favorável. Outra coisa nunca faça uma pesquisa pela metade, tudo que for fazer mediante filtro faça antes do `ToList()`.

Existe um pacote no nuget o [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/), pode ser utilizando tranquilamente para atualizar campos isolados, com a seguinte sintaxe para o seu problema:

```c#
db.Tabela
   .Where(l => l.Nome == "João" && l.estado == "SP")
   .Update(w => new Tabela { estado = "São Paulo" });
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Tipos anônimos (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/bb397696.aspx)
- [Expressões de consulta LINQ (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397676.aspx)
- [Cláusula select (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb384087.aspx)
- [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/)
- [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#entity-framework-extended-library)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta ajudou aqui.